# A way to get the count of non zero values in a coo_matrix of pythons scipy module?

Tags: python, count, scipy, sparse-matrix

I thought of using `coo_matrix.nonzero()` which returns a tuple of two arrays which contain the indices of the nonzero entrys in a given matrix. The example from the docs states:

```
>>> from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix
>>> A = coo_matrix([[1,2,0],[0,0,3],[4,0,5]])
>>> nonzero_entrys = A.nonzero()
(array([0, 0, 1, 2, 2]), array([0, 1, 2, 0, 2]))
```

Then I would do something like `len(nonzero_entrys[0])` but this seem like a diversion. Is there a better way I have overlooked in the docs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `len(A.data)` instead.

Comment: This *is* better then my approach! :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The coo_matrix object has an attribute specifically giving non-zero values, called `.nzz` .

As an example, generate an 5x5 identify matrix.

```
sparse = scipy.sparse.coo_matrix(np.diag(np.ones(5)))
sparse.nnz
5
```

You can read more about it and find other handy attributes by doing `help(scipy.sparse.coo_matrix)`